# React navigation Stack Navigator componentdidMount

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using react-navigation. Using stack navigator and a drawer nested inside it.How to call componentdidmount and this.props.navgation.navigate in the code below. I have some event which is supposed to navigate user to particular screen rather than following initial route of Drawer.

```
 import React from "react";
    import { Platform, Text } from "react-native";
    import { Root } from "native-base";
    import { StackNavigator, DrawerNavigator} from "react-navigation";
    import Register from "./components/Register";
    import Home from "./components/home/";
    import Dashboard from "./components/Dashboard/";
    import SideBar from "./components/sidebar";
    import Screen1 from "./components/Screen1/";
    import Screen2 from "./components/Screen2/";
    import Screen3 from "./components/Screen3/";

    const Drawer = DrawerNavigator(
      {
        Dashboard: { screen: Dashboard },
        Screen1: { screen: Screen1 },
        Screen2 : { screen: Screen2 },
      },
      {
        navigationOptions: {
          gesturesEnabled: false,
        },
       initialRouteName: "Dashboard",
        contentOptions: {
          activeTintColor: "#e91e63"
        },
        drawerPosition: 'right',
        contentComponent: props => <SideBar {...props} />
      }
    );


    const AppNavigator = StackNavigator(
        {
            Home: { screen: Home },
            Register: { screen: Register },
            Drawer: { screen: Drawer },
            Screen3: { screen: Screen3 },
        },
        {

             headerMode: "none",

        }
    );


//HOW TO WRITE COMPONENTDIDMOUNT HERE AND CALL //THIS.PROPS.NAVIGATION.NAVIGATE
    export default () =>
        <Root>
            <AppNavigator />
        </Root>;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating a component, then you won't be able to "write" `ComponentDidMount` here.

`<Root>` have it's own `componentDidMount`, which runs when you render it.

Be sure to have a good understanding of how *React* and *JSX* work together :
https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html